# How to ask for a salary re-evaluation after relocation?

Tags: salary, relocation, japan

I have been working for the same company for 7 years.  Recently I have been relocated from France to Japan (8 months ago now), same title and just a bit more responsibilities.

In France I was at the average of the salary expectation for my title (Project manager & System engineer), but in Japan I'm at 15%+ under the average amount (even inside the company itself).

I didn't ask for the relocate, it was asked by the company as the Japanese branch was in need of a PM with my skill set.

Considering that Japanese companies have a really vertical hierarchy I am wondering if it would not cripple me more than anything. This cultural wall is my main concern.

Should I, and how can I, bring this conversation to the table?

For the possible duplicate: concern is the culture wall, answer will probably end-up being the same, but I would like to get input about the correct way to do it in japan.

Update to answer some question:

-Salary is paid by french branch until end of this month.

-Japan's tax are 50% lower than France one's.

-Relocation include possibility to go back to France at any given time.

-As the japanese branch is new and growing fast, it will be easier to climb the ladder in Japan.

-I have perfect records (in both country).

-After the golden week (May), we have the first performance review for 2017 (would be the perfect time in EU/France).

-I report to both directions, Japan's for management, France's for monitoring the branch evolution.

Comment: You relocated to a different country (on the other side of the planet!) and you did not ask for a big raise? You had large pull then (obviously the company needed you there and if they ask someone from so far away they seem to be desperate) and before accepting the relocation would have been a good time to ask for a big raise. I am not sure if you have any leverage now.

Comment: Your salary negotiation should have been part of the company asking you to move.  At this point what leverage do you have?  Having said that, yes why not ask?

Comment: Japan's life cost is far lower than french one, so even at the salary staying the same Im saving far more(tax in Japan are pretty low). As for leverage, I still have the opporunity to move back to France as soon as I want -this part was negociate-. I think I still have the same leverage as without me all current project are dead/will not be done in time.

Comment: Who do you report to?  A manager in Japan or in France?

Comment: In addition to @JohnK.'s question:  Who is paying your salary, the Japanese branch or the French branch?  My boss is currently on loan from another plant and is paid by his home plant in his home currency.

Comment: @Myles updated post, also Im paid in japanese Yen.

Comment: First, check the employee manuals and check with the HR of both countries, starting with France first, to make sure you're not leaving any free money on the table like your daily allowance for expenses, relocation bonus, extra vacation time, free two-way return flights for holidays, differences in health benefits/pension, etc. Once you've done that part, talk to your higher-ups, starting with the French ones first. Do not wait. Fight for that raise now and fight for another raise during your review. The raise after performance reviews may be highly regimented and also capped to a maximum.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer on Japan (which I realise is the crux of you question), but will answer generally.

> it was asked by the company as the Japanese branch was in need of a PM with my skill set

Yes, in this situation you **should** renegotiate your position/salary, to reflect the location (living and/or tax differences etc, unless of course you're actually in a better position), plus your obvious importance (and the fact you are doing them a favour).  You could also look for a move up the ladder in position to address your move (and this may be a better option than money).

However, the time to do this was before you made the move, you have signalled that you were willing to make the move on the same deal.  It's possible it may have made a difference to you being asked if you had re-negotiated.

So you can (and probably should) ask, but be aware that the boat may have sailed already.

I would take the line of how you were wanting to help the company, and interested in the opportunity, so admit you may have been under prepared on doing due-diligence on such a move. Now you've had time to settle you wonder if there is any room for an increase/promotion/both given how quickly you made the transition and the continued good work you are doing even with regional differences.  Then go on to demonstrate the value you've brought to them.